# Second screen working but doesn't display anything

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, black-screen-of-death

thanks for passing by

I've ran into an issue lately ; I have a PC with two screens, one being HDMI plugged to the GPU (GTX 2080 Ti) and the other connected to the MoBo's HDMI port : Intel UHD Graphics 630.

The thing is, both screens work when I start the PC but as soon as I put it to sleep, only the GPU one is working, the one connected to the Mobo only displaying the mouse cursor. It still is recognized by the system and Win + CTRL + Shift + B doesn't change a thing.

At first I thought it was because the driver was corrupted, but turns out it isn't as simple : I used Chrome Remote Desktop to see if both screens were working and yes, from Chrome Remote Desktop it turns out the screen is working fine, I can move windows to it and use it normally, while it doesn't seem to work on the PC, it does work fine on Chrome Remote Desktop.

What I've tried ;

- Reinstalling the Intel drivers,
- Using only this screen and putting the PC to sleep
- Disabling Hibernate and put the PC to sleep
- Changing the screen's settings and the Intel Graphics settings in-app
- Changing the power options for said intel screen

What I've observed :

- If I change any setting of said screen in the Intel Graphics application, it turns black and doesn't change back (need reboot)
- If I uninstall the Intel drivers and reboot Windows without installing them, they will do so on their own and work fine
- Any issue I came by was resolved by restarting the PC, which lead me to think that the problem lies in the fact that the screen state changes, which a driver or Windows doesn't support, thus creating this issue.

Thanks for your time and dedication !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears this is a Windows problem that sometimes comes from the incompatibility between the two graphic drivers used simultaneously (one from Intel HD Graphic Cards and the other from NVIDIA) and that there is not real fix to that, I search quite a bit

The only solution, the thing I did, was to take a HDMI - DisplayPort cable, it has since worked flawlessly